# Need prize award function given rank and a pot amount

Tags: math, distribution

I need a formula to assign proportion of a prize award to participants in the contest.

The top *n* winners should get a proportion of the total prize amount *x* based on their rank order.

However the top winners should get a *disproportionate* amount of the prize amount, e.g. given *n*=3 and *x*=2500 the top winner gets something on the order $1500, the next 750, the last $250. *n* and *x* can vary, obviously.

What kind of function given *n*, *x* and the *rank* of a given participant could return a proportion of *x* for that *rank*, the sum of which for all possible values of *rank* (bounded by *n*) would be equal to *x*? And which would be monotone, but not linear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way I can control the degree of slope? – ʞɔıu

Yes.  Use:

[image: (x (z - 1) z^(n - r))/(z^n - 1)]

Where `z` is a scaling factor greater than one, `r` is rank, `n` is number of recipients, and `x` is total prize money.

For example, here is $10,000 divided among 12 people, each getting 2X the previous:

[image]

{5001.22, 2500.61, 1250.31, 625.153, 312.576, 156.288, 78.1441, 39.072, 19.536, 9.76801, 4.884, 2.442}

---

You implicitly asked how I derived this.  Allow me to show you, using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

I first describe the problem for a case of three people in terms of inequalities:

```
{a + b + c == x, x > a > b > c > 0, z > 1, a == b z, b == c z}
```

[I then ask WolframAlpha to solve this.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Reduce%5B%7Ba%20%2b%20b%20%2b%20c%20==%20x,%20x%20%3E%20a%20%3E%20b%20%3E%20c%20%3E%200,%20z%20%3E%201,%20a%20==%20b%20z,%20%20b%20==%20c%20z%7D,%20c%5D)  `Reduce` is a Mathematica command that WolframAlpha accepts.

That gives the result:

[image]

I also tried the case of four people.  From those results I concluded the formula was:

```
(x*z^(n - r))/Sum[z^i, {i, 0, n - 1}]
```

[And asked WolframAlpha to evaluate it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x*z%5E%28n%20-%20r%29%29/Sum%5Bz%5Ei,%20%7Bi,%200,%20n%20-%201%7D%5D), which returns:

[image]

Now you've seen behind the curtain. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This question is awesome! :)
I'm afraid I can't (don't know how to) put summation notation in here, so let me use words.

`prizeMoney = (summation: i=r to n) of x/in`

So if n = 3

rank = 1 gets `x/3 + x/6 + x/9`

rank = 2 gets `x/6 + x/9`

rank = 3 gets `x/9`

The grand total is `x/3 + 2x/6 + 3x/9 = 3x/3 = x`

Comment: Is there any way I can control the degree of slope?